# binding the background color of a gradient inside of a WPF listbox datatemplate

Tags: wpf, binding

So I have a datatemplate and there is board in it, here is what I wan to do.

```
<Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
 <Border.Background>
  <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="Transparent"/>
    <GradientStop 
     Color="{Binding Condition, Converter={StaticResourc ConditionTypeToColorConveter}}"    Offset="0.541"/>
  </LinearGradientBrush>
 </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

I can see the converter being called no problem. but the color it returns isn't displayed. Now if I do this

```
<Border Grid.Column="0" 
 Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
 Background="{Binding Condition, Converter={StaticResourc ConditionTypeToColorConveter}}">
```

It works just fine - of course - I don't want it to be all one color I need it to be a gradient.

Anyone have any idea what is wrong with this? it's making me batty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't work because in the first example you bind a `Color` in the second a `Brush`. What type your converter returns? You named it 'ToColor' but it is working as a `Brush` for `Background`.